# Using method function in v-if

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I’m trying to use a function in a v-if directive like that in a vue template

```
    <template>

    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">
            <div class="row">
                <div v-for="col in colss" class="" :class="bootstrapClass">{{col | capitalize}}</div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li v-for="item in datas[collectionsindatas['reference']]" class="list-group-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div v-for="property in columns.slice(0,(columns.length))" class="" :class="bootstrapClass">{{ item[property] }}</div>

                <div v-if="compareCollections(item[comparecol],datas[collectionsindatas['compare'][comparecol]])" class="" :class="bootstrapClass">
                    OK
                </div>
                <div v-else class="" :class="bootstrapClass">!!NOK!!</div>

            </div>

        </li>
    </ul>

</template>
```

and my methods are like that :

```
methods:{
compareCollections:function(reference,compare){
                if(compare!='undefined'  && compare!=''){
                    if(compare===reference){
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            },
}
```

It fails with this message : [Vue warn]: Property or method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

It fells myself better to use a method instead writing many things ugly in the v-if directive like

```
v-if="datas[collectionsindatas['compare'][comparecol]]!='undefined'&&(item[comparecol]===datas[collectionsindatas['compare'][comparecol]])"
```

what is the right way to do this ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why not use a helper method instead with the exact same content and call it in the `v-if` instead? Possibly a computed value, if you need it.

Comment: computed don't accept parameters... The function that is exposed here takes place in methods.

Comment: It doesn't need to as long as the callback can call the same parameters. Is it because you use this in loop that exposes the `item`, `comparecol`, `datas` etc. variables? Why not simply get them from the method instead of through the `v-if`?

Comment: Can you provide more information of what is around the <div> here?

Comment: Assuming the message come from the `<div v-if...`, it means one (or more) of `comparecol, datas, collectionsindatas` is not defined on the component. Can you please share props and data?

Comment: **computed don't accept parameters** - see [Can computed property be a function which itself return another function](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/can-computed-property-be-a-function-which-itself-return-another-function/7572), From LinusBorg, **Yes, sure**

Comment: I've changed my way of thinking, now i'm passing an array of my references datas and on the ajax success event i'm comparing and passing a comparing result array to my props so it will be cleaner I think.

Comment: Does that mean you are no longer getting the error message?

Comment: yes by changing this way, because now I'm not using a v-if, the comparison is made on the ajax success event. It's a workaround, I don't have find any documentation talking about having a function with parameters binded to a v-if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it could be improved but here is my way to resolve this :

My list component receive by props a reference list of avalaible permissions and receive a comparing list to the role's permission so when the comparing returns true it will display a toggle switch wich appear set on ON position and OFF if it's false.
So here is the app.js :

```
Vue.component('sort-table', sortTable);
Vue.component('list-items', listItems);

var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

var newTable = new Vue({
    el: '#appTableRoles',
    data: {

        columns: ['id', 'name', 'description', 'action'],
        cols: ['Id', 'Rôle', 'Description', 'Actions'],
        // ajax url
        url: 'Role/ajaxQuery',

    },
    components: {sortTable},

});

var listTable = new Vue({
    el: '#listmodal',
    data: {
        // collection des propriétés
        columns: ['id', 'name', 'description'],
        // collection d'affichage
        colss: ['Id', 'Nom', 'Description', 'Attribution'],
        urlajax:'',
        datas:[],
        //
        collectionsInDatas:{'reference':'allPermissions','compare':'rolePermissions'},
        // critère de comparaison entre la collection de référence et la collection appartenant à l'item
        comparecol:'name',
        //objet contenant tous les résultats de comparaisons
        lastcol:{equal:[],display:[]},

    },
    methods: {
        showModal () {
            $('#permissionsModal').modal('show');
        },
        hideModal () {
            $('#permissionsModal').modal('hide');
        },

        getDatas(){

            this.lastcol.equal =[];
            this.lastcol.display =[];

            MonThis = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: this.urlajax,
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    if (jqXHR.status === 200) {
                        //console.log(data);
                        MonThis.datas = data;
                        var index=0;
                        //console.log(MonThis.datas[MonThis.collectionsInDatas['reference']]);
                        for(item in MonThis.datas[MonThis.collectionsInDatas['reference']]){

                            //var index = MonThis.datas[MonThis.collectionsInDatas['reference']].indexOf(item);
                            //console.log('index : '+index);

                            console.log('reference name : '+MonThis.datas[MonThis.collectionsInDatas['reference']][index]['name']);
                            //console.log('compare : '+MonThis.datas[MonThis.collectionsInDatas['compare']][index]);

                            var j = 0;
                            for(compare in MonThis.datas[MonThis.collectionsInDatas['compare']]){

                                //console.log('compare name : '+MonThis.datas[MonThis.collectionsInDatas['compare']][j]['name']);

                                if(MonThis.datas[MonThis.collectionsInDatas['compare']][j]['name']===MonThis.datas[MonThis.collectionsInDatas['reference']][index]['name']){
                                    MonThis.lastcol.equal.push(true);
                                    MonThis.lastcol.display.push('OK');
                                    break;
                                }else{
                                    MonThis.lastcol.equal.push(false);
                                    MonThis.lastcol.display.push('Not OK');
                                }
                                j++;

                            }

                            index++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        },


    },
    components:{listItems},

});

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('click', '.modal-permissions', function (e) {
        //console.log($(e.target).attr('href'));
        listTable.showModal();
        listTable.$data.urlajax = $(e.target).attr('href');
        listTable.getDatas();

    });

});
```

Here is the component call in the blade template :

```
<list-items :colss="colss":columns="columns"
            :urlajax="urlajax"
            :datas="datas"
            :lastcol="lastcol"
            :collectiondatas="collectionsInDatas">
</list-items>
```

and Here is the vue file code :

```
    <template>

    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">
            <div class="row">
                <div v-for="col in colss" class="" :class="bootstrapClass">{{col | capitalize}}</div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li v-for="(item,index ) in datas[collectiondatas['reference']]" class="list-group-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div v-for="property in columns.slice(0,(columns.length))" class="" :class="bootstrapClass">{{
                    item[property] }}</div>


                <div class="" :class="bootstrapClass">{{ lastcol.display[index] }}</div>

            </div>

        </li>
    </ul>

</template>

<script>

    var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

    export default {

        name: 'listItems',

        data(){
            return {


            }
        },

        props: ['colss','columns','lastcol','urlajax','datas','collectiondatas'],

        methods: {



        },

        computed: {
            bootstrapClass: function() {
                return 'col-sm-' + (12 / this.colss.length );
            },


        },

        mounted: function () {


        },

        filters: {

            capitalize: function (str) {
                return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
            }

        },

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to get rid of this comparison in your `v-if` I'd use a component with your parameters. In the component you can calculate the values and provide them using `computed`. You won't have to pass any parameters to `computed` because they will already be the parameters of the component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="compEqRef" class="" :class="bootstrapClass">
      OK
    </div>
    <div v-else class="" :class="bootstrapClass">!!NOK!!</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {

    methods: {
      compareCollections(reference, compare) {
        return (compare !== 'undefined' && compare !== '' && compare === reference);
      }
    },

    computed: {
      compEqRef() {
        const left = this.item[this.comparecol];
        const right = this.datas[this.collectionsindatas['compare'][this.comparecol]];

        return this.compareCollections(left, right);
      }
    },

    props: {
      item: {
        required: true
      },
      datas: {
        required: true
      },
      comparecol: {
        required: true
      },
      collectionsindatas: {
        required: true
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help it seems very complicated just to compare 2 strings.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to use [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example) you won't be able to pass parameters to the computed property, but you can interact with the state of your component.

Comment: computed properties are not reactive, v-if won't work with them

Comment: @Extrapolator That's incorrect. Computed properties are reactive. "computed properties are cached based on their reactive dependencies. A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its reactive dependencies have changed."  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods

Answer (score 0):

If your method returns a boolean you can use

```
v-if="!!compareCollections(params)"
```

simple and clean

Comment: If the method returns a boolean you don't need to cast again so you can remove the `!!`. But isn't calling functions from a template like this frowned upon in Vue (not sure, but I seem to recall it is)